# How do I query for values of symbols in a closure in R?

Tags: r, closures, environment

How can I query the value of x for foo in the R code below?

```
make.foo <- function() {
    x <- 123
    function() x * 3
}

foo <- make.foo()

# now get foo's x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function will have an environment

from `` ?`function` ``

> A closure has three components, its formals (its argument list), its body (expr in the ‘Usage’ section) and its environment which provides the enclosure of the evaluation frame when the closure is used.

so you can `get` from that environment (or  list the objects using `ls`)

```
get('x', envir = environment(foo))
## [1] 123
```

or if you want to know all the objects  in the environment

```
ls(envir = environment(foo))
## 'x'
```

and if you want to assign to that environment (ie change `x`)

```
assign('x', 24, envir = environment(foo))

foo()
## 72
```

You can even remove it from the environment

```
rm(x, envir = environment(foo))
foo()
## Error in foo() : object 'x' not found
```

and then use a globally assigned `x`

```
x <- 3
foo()
# [1] 9
```

and reassign to the `function`'s environment

```
assign('x', 123, envir = environment(foo))
foo()
## [1] 369
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to look for something in an object's environment ***and nowhere else*** then use `get` with `inherits=FALSE`. Otherwise you'll risk finding things in the function's parent environment. Example using your `make.foo` above:

```
> z=999
> get("x",environment(foo))
[1] 123
> get("z",environment(foo))
[1] 999
> get("x",environment(foo),inherits=FALSE)
[1] 123
> get("z",environment(foo),inherits=FALSE)
Error in get("z", environment(foo), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'z' not found
```

The second `get` shows that you might not get an error if you try and get something that isn't in the closure's environment if it appears in the parent environment. This may cause odd bugs. With `inherits=FALSE` you get an immediate error.